# Where is compactness used?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $K$ is a compact subset and $F$ a closed subset of a metric space $X$ such that $K \cap F = \varnothing$. The question I am working on wants me to show that $0 < \inf\{d(x, y) : x \in K, y \in F\}$.

Below is my proof:

Let $f(x) := \inf\{d(x, y) : y \in F\}$. Then $f$ is a function on $K$. We want to show that $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in K$. Suppose there was an $x_{0} \in K$ such that $f(x_{0}) = 0$. Then there would exists a sequence $\{y_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ of elements of $F$ such that $d(x_{0}, y_{n}) < 1/n$. This implies that $x_{0}$ is a limit point of $F$ and hence $x_{0} \in F$ since $F$ is closed. This contradicts the fact that $F \cap K = \varnothing$.

My question is: Where is compactness of $K$ used?

Answer (score 4):

Your argument is not quite complete. You have shown that $f(K)\subseteq(0,\infty)$, but this does not imply that $\displaystyle\inf_{x\in K}f(x)\neq 0$. To argue this, you have to note that by compactness of $K$, $f(K)$ is compact as well and that hence $\displaystyle\inf_{x\in K} f(x) \in f(K) \subseteq(0,\infty)$.

Comment: The assumion that $K$ is closed is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You used compactness when you started your contradiction argument.

"Suppose there was an $x_0 \in K$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$."

If $K$ were not compact, then this would not be the only case to consider for the assumption $\textrm{inf } f(x) = 0$. For example, what if $f$ attained every positive value, but just not zero?

Since $K$ is compact, you know that $f$ has a minimum value, i.e. there is some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ actually equals $\textrm{inf } f(x)$.

Comment: The assumion that $K$ is closed is enough.

Comment: No, it is not. A function on a closed set need not have a minimum. In fact, the same idea can be used to show the thoerem does not hold if $K$ is not assumed compact, instead of just closed. Consider the metric space $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the two closed sets $F$ and $K$, where $F$ is the real line and $K$ is the graph of the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$. These two closed sets are disjoint but have distance zero.

Comment: Note: In my first comment, $K$ is the set of points $\{(x, \frac{1}{x}): x > 0\}$, a closed set even though the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined on a closed set. For an example of a function on a closed set with no minimum, consider the closed subset $[0, \infty)$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function that is always positive but has $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. Now, the range of $f$ does not include zero, but the infimum of its range does include zero.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your argument is correct.

I would have proved it in this way going along your lines.

Let if possible $\inf \{d(x,y)|x\in K,y\in F\}=0$

Then $\forall n\in N,\exists x_n\in K,y_n\in F$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)<1/n$

So we get a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $K$. Now as $K$ is compact so $\exists \{x_{n_k}\}\subseteq \{x_n\}\text{ and } x\in K$ such that $x_{n_k}\to x$ as $k\to \infty$

So for some large enough $N_1\in N$ we must have $d(y_{n_k},x)\le d(y_n,x_{n_k})+d(x_{n_k},x)\le \epsilon /2+\epsilon /2=\epsilon$ for  all $k\ge N_1$

So we have ,

$y_{n_k}\to x$ as $k\to \infty$ and as $F$ is closed so $x\in F$

So we have $x\in F\cap K$ which is a contradiction.

Hence $\inf \{d(x,y)|x\in K,y\in F\}\ne 0$